# How can I resolve Error: Cannot find module “.” in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So, I am trying to build an ionic project for production, It's working fine in debug, if I serve it doesn't show any error but when I try to build or run android it throws me two different error, the IDE vs code or webstrom not showing any error not it is importing something after ionic-angular. One is, see image attached:

> Error: Cannot find module “.”

Possible solution is reducing typescript version, but I can not reduce that as I need latest typescript version for rxjs 6.* and I can not reduce rxjs version too. So hands are tied, tried all other possible solution in the internet. 
Another error is showing up that is

> the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file
>   ///android_asset/www/index.html)

but that's not major right now.

PS: All the question from stackoverflow with similar title doesn't work. So it's not duplicate of others.

[image]

Comment: it's look like aciddentally you remove the path in an import, check if you has some like `import {something} from '.'`

Comment: @Eliseo No, I checked line by line. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, After a lot of R&D I found the solution.
The problem is **Ionic 3 doesn't support rxjs6** and I was using Angularfire in the project that required rxjs6. What's the solution than?

Create a new project, if you're using firebase than connect with older version of it probably 4.12.1 cause newer version have type definition where you need to upgrade typescript but you don't wanna do that, connect with Angularfire2 if you were using Angularfire, Intialize  it, create a build for production. 
You may face some error that are easily solvable, after the build of production, replace pages, services and assets folders, install plugins/packages you need, define the pages and service in app module, copy paste you app.component, html, scss/css code carefully. Fix the path of AngularFire if you are using it, you may need to fix some queries too.

So that's the problem I was facing, you may face different one, *check for any plugin/package you need to upgrade your rxjs/typescript* that throws the error.